# select from three table to Create dynamic menu control in asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a select query from three tables to show item and sub item (level on) and sub sub item(level two), my problem is when I select with using join I get more than item1 in the result of the query in case the item1 have more than one sub, so I need the query to complete this menu and this us the three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category] (

            [CategoryID] [int]  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY ,

            [CategoryName] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,

            [Remarks] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategorySub] (

            [SubCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL ,

            [CategoryIDToSub] [int] NULL ,

            [SubCategoryName] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,

            [RcatID] [int] NULL ,

            [RsubID] [int] NULL ,

            [Rsub2ID] [int] NULL ,

            [Remarks] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategorySub2] (

            [Sub2CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL ,

            [SubCategoryID] [int] NULL ,

            [Sub2CategoryName] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,

            [RcatID] [int] NULL ,

            [RsubID] [int] NULL ,

            [Rsub2ID] [int] NULL ,

            [Remarks] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL


) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

While not an answer to your question directly - if you in any way can, I'd suggest changing the schema. The current one is confusing to read with all the different naming schemes, not to mention that it's hardcoded & limited to three levels. A more scalable solution, provided you're running on SQL Server 2005+ would be to use a single self-referencing Category table and then query it recursively using a Common Table Expression:

```
CREATE TABLE #Category
(
    CategoryID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ParentID int NULL,
    Name nvarchar(500),
);

WITH TMP AS
(
    SELECT
        CategoryID,
        Name,
        0 AS Level
    FROM
        #Category
    WHERE
        ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        C.CategoryID,
        C.Name,
        Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM
        #Category C
    INNER JOIN
        TMP ON TMP.CategoryID = C.ParentID
)
SELECT
    CategoryID,
    Name
FROM
    TMP
```

The above supports virtually unlimited levels of nesting and you'll get all your categories out with their ID's, a ParentID indicating the ID of the parent row, as well as a Level indicator going from 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: the problem is i'm confined with this tables because i'm working in exist project